# Execute KILL command from JAVA_OPTS using -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

I am trying to execute kill command on OnOutOfMemoryError for a SpringBoot application.
Below is the .conf file having command.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512M -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)\""
```

If I run Spring boot application as "java -jar" with Java Hostspot VM commands it works fine, but while running as Linux systemd service, application is not getting killed.

```
Exception  : "Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"
```

Comment: you can maybe replace ```-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)\``` by  ```-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError```

Comment: Thanks @Albanninou. But I have openjdk version "1.8.0_242" and I think exitOnMemoryError needs upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I run an instance of GeoServer using tomcat with a container in the docker swarm.

I expect swarm to recreate the container after any problem with this instance, but after an OutOfMemory error, the container will never be restarted because the JVM is still running, although the application no longer responds.
For this case, I use OnOutOfMemoryError and the container is eliminated after this type of error, so that the swarm can recreate it.

Tomcat environment to set the JVM parameters.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"kill -9 %p\"
-Djava.awt.headless=true \
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server \
-Xms1024m -Xmx3072m -Xss1024k -XX:NewSize=768m \
-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500"
```

You can try to adapt it to your use.

Importantly, i use these software:

- Tomcat 9
- OpenJDK-11
- GeoServer 2.16.x
- Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Docs for consult JVM openJDK-11 configuration options: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/openjdk-11-jre-headless/java.1.en.html